# First order expansion in D dimension in an integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration

I'm trying to understand the following passage, from  A. Schakel Boulevard of broken symmetries (page 135). He's evaluating the normal mass current density in a superfluid. It starts with the following integral:

$$-\int\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{\hbar\vec{k}}{e^{\beta[E(\vec{k})-\hbar(\vec{v_s}-\vec{v})\vec{k}]}-1}$$
And then , expanding in $\vec{v_s}-\vec{v}$ at first order:

$$\frac{\beta}{D}\int\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}\hbar^2\vec{k}^2\frac{e^{\beta E(\vec{k})}}{(e^{\beta E(\vec{k})}-1)^2}(\vec{v}-\vec{v_s})$$
The only issue i have with this expansion is that i cannot get the factor $\frac{1}{D}$ in front of the integral. I believe that this comes from expansion of the denominator but i could not find a definite answer.

Comment: Your first equation is missing a closing bracket on the denominator

Comment: Besides the 1/D, are you sure of your formula ? I tried doing the expansion, and I have a scalar product of k with (v-v_s), rather than a norm squared.

Could you specify if there is a scalar product with (v-v_s) and k in the exponential, or is it a multiplication of norms ? In either case I really don't know where the 1/D would be coming from

Comment: Perhaps: $k^ik^k=\frac{1}{D}\delta^{ij}\vec k^2$.